# How to scan Windows Partition using ClamAv? "Could not mount OS"

Tags: dual-boot, mount, clamav

I am new to Ubuntu. I was trying to scan my Windows 10 partition using ClamAv but whenever I select the Windows Partition, this message pops up:

```
Could not mount OS. 
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/username/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/username/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."
```

I have restarted the computer, with Windows fully shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Tthe error message says Windows is hibernated, and restarting the computer back to Ubuntu won't correct that -- you need to boot into Windows, and do a full shutdown/restart rather than a hibernate before starting Ubuntu.  I'd generally recommend using a Windows malware scanner while you have Windows open, but that's up to you; if ClamAV has Windows malware signatures, it may do the job (I don't know ClamAV).

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. *nix systems are scanning for Windows malware (e. g. in local networks) since decades and there are many professional products marketed with that purpose, ClamAV being one of them. Also, signature matching is still the major method of malware detection (whether that's a good strategy is another question) and it works independently of the execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just boot into your Windows partition and execute

1. `powercfg -h off` followed by
2. `shutdown /s /t 0`

The first command will turn off hibernate.

The second one will ensure complete shutdown.

Just make sure to execute the commands as administrator.

Then, from Ubuntu you will be able to mount the partition.